# Function to return after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise, settimeout

So I have this function which I would like to run:

```
const normal = () => {
  return 'working
}
```

I can log its output and it works fine:

```
console.log(normal()) // does output: 'working'
```

Now I would like to run a function `delayed` which is exactly the same as `normal` only it takes 3 seconds before returning

I would like to be able to log this function call but only after 3 seconds, I am understandably logging `undefined` at the moment and have a feeling that it might be possible to do. Anyway I want the following to happen, the function to hang for 3 seconds, then return data:

```
console.log(delayed()) // should output: 'working'
```

My attempts:

```
const toReturn = () => {
  return 'working'
}

const runner = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(cb, 1000)
}

export const delayed = () => {
  return runner(toReturn)
}

console.log(delayed()) // currently outputting: undefined
```

undefined is because I am not returning anything from runner, if I `return setTimout...` in runner, I simply get the whole setTimout function, which is pretty useless.

I know you can simply log after 3 seconds within a callback, but I would like to log what is returned from a setTimeout

Comment: You mean, lock the users' browser for 3 seconds? Sure you can do it! But don't expect any positive feedback. This will make the system unresponsive and destroy your users' work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `console.log` (or anything else) it's going to take that action then. JS is not like some languages where you pause code execution.

If you want the `console.log` to be delayed then you need to delay the actual call to `console.log`, not the return of the value you're logging.

The simplest way would be something like this:

```
function delayedLog(seconds)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        var val = getSomething(); // <- pretend this returns "later"
        console.log(val); // <- after 3 seconds logs "later"
    }, seconds*1000);
}

console.log('now');
delayedLog(3);
```